# way to delete beginning of chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I want to do a chat application using the Firebase Realtime Database where many people can chat together at the same time. All Messages should be stored in there:

```
->1
   ->user
   ->message

->2
   ->user
   ->message
...
```

But if the number of messages gets too high (for example  200), the last 10 should be deleted.

So what I tried (but obviously it's not the best solution) is the following:
You could let every phone do this which looks like the following:

```
myReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 200){
                    //Here would be the code to delete it
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you looking for a "better" way to do this then is that your question?

Comment: If you are looking for discussion on this one of the search terms is "cache replacement".

Comment: @EdNorman Yes, That is what I am looking for

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: Alex Mamo: Problem is that you code in Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Functionally, your approach of having clients take care of managing the messages would probably work, but as you suspect, it's not the best solution. For one, it implies the clients have to be authorized to delete/modify all messages, regardless of which user posted them (the oldest messages may have been posted by any user, after all). Even without knowing your exact use-case, I doubt you want to allow one user to delete messages posted by someone else.

Instead, the functionality you're describing sounds like it should be the responsibility of the server, not the client.

To that end, you can leverage Firebase's [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) (specifically through [Realtime Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), most likely), which should allow you to run effectively the same "onChildAdded" code you described, but on the server.
That way, you only need to authorize the *server* to modify all messages, and the client doesn't have to be involved.

(Note: Though it doesn't look that way from your schema, if you actually meant you want to only keep the 200 most recent messages *per user*, authorization would be less of a concern. Still, it would probably be a good idea to put this kind of responsibility on the server side, if only because it allows you to change the logic whenever you want, without having to deploy a new version to your clients. In general, this kind of "data maintenance" just fundamentally fits better as the responsibility of the server.)

Comment: Thanks, I think that really helps me!

Comment: Is there a way to insert Java or Python code instead of other languages?

Comment: Sure, seems like they support Python and Go in addition to Node.js: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview.